# Does this structured matrix yielding a specified characteristic polynomial admit uniquely defined Jordan blocks?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, jordan-normal-form

Let $\mathcal E \subset M_5(\mathbb R)$ be a subset of matrices defined by: for every $A \in \mathcal E$, $A$ admits the structure
\begin{align*}
 A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & * & 0 & 0 & * \\
1 & * & 0 & 0 & * \\
0 & * & 0 & 0 & * \\
0 & * & 1 & 0 & *\\
0 & * & 0 &1 & *
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $*$ means it can assume any real value.

Suppose we have a monic polynomial $p(t) = (t-a)^5$ with $a \in \mathbb R$. I am wondering whether the matrices in $\mathcal E$ such that $\chi_{A}(t) = p(t)$ have uniquely defined Jordan blocks (up to permutation) where $\chi_A(t)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Apparently, if we realize $p(t)$ in block diagonal manner, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
 A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -a^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -3a^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 &1 & 3a
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
then there are two Jordan blocks, with size $2$ and size $3$. I feel that other realizations should give the same Jordan blocks, but not sure how to formally argue this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. For the $A$ below, we have $A^3\ne0=A^4$:
$$
A=\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0}.
$$